# Arduino, ambilight main loop for displaying LEDs and error handling

Tags: c++, error-handling, arduino, serial-port, rgb

i have made ambilight on arduino and now im trying to figure how it works. This is main loop of the program which is displaying LEDS.

Can somebody tell me what does first loop (what is magic word), Hi, Lo, Checksum and If checksum does not match go back to wait.

```
void loop() { 
  // Wait for first byte of Magic Word
  for(i = 0; i < sizeof prefix; ++i) {
    waitLoop: while (!Serial.available()) ;;
    // Check next byte in Magic Word
    if(prefix[i] == Serial.read()) continue;
    // otherwise, start over
    i = 0;
    goto waitLoop;
  }
  
  // Hi, Lo, Checksum  
  while (!Serial.available()) ;;
  hi=Serial.read();
  while (!Serial.available()) ;;
  lo=Serial.read();
  while (!Serial.available()) ;;
  chk=Serial.read();
  
  // If checksum does not match go back to wait
  if (chk != (hi ^ lo ^ 0x55)) {
    i=0;
    goto waitLoop;
  }
  
  memset(leds, 0, NUM_LEDS * sizeof(struct CRGB));
  // Read the transmission data and set LED values
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    byte r, g, b;    
    while(!Serial.available());
    r = Serial.read();
    while(!Serial.available());
    g = Serial.read();
    while(!Serial.available());
    b = Serial.read();
    leds[i].r = r;
    leds[i].g = g;
    leds[i].b = b;
  }
  
  // Shows new values
  FastLED.show();
}
```

Comment: those are comments

Comment: Where did you copy the code from? Did you read the comment from the code you copied that explained the prefix structure that the code referred to as "magic word"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The code decoding what is generally called as the "Adalight protocol", it consists of a 3-byte prefix as the "magic word" {'A', 'd', 'a'} or "Ada"), followed by  a `uint16_t` value in big endian format that represents the number of LEDs - 1, followed by 16-bit checksum. LED data follows, 3 bytes per LED, in order R, G, B (where 0 = off and 255 = max brightness).

By the way, wherever you copy your code from, it is not well written. You could find better implementation online.